# SQL: Eliminate rows that have one duplicate values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have  a table that may contain duplicate values in one column.  For each distinct value in that column I  need to select only  the row with the smallest index.  I have tried many combinations of distinct() min() and group by but have not been able to figure this  one  out.  This query will be run on sql server 2008.

```
color  |  index  |  user_id | organization_code
blue      44         xxx            yyy
blue      66         xxx            yyy
red       12         aaa            bbb
white     55         ccc            ddd
white     68         xxx            yyy
```

The  query would  return the first, third and fourth rows.

```
blue      44         xxx            yyy
red       12         aaa            bbb
white     55         ccc            ddd
```

Comment: "one column", "that column", ... I could guess that the one that you're referring to here is `color`, or `user_id` or `organization_code` - would you care to actually specify which column is "that column".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but you correctly read my mind.  In my example the color column contains the duplicates of interest.  The other duplicates are the result of hasty typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use keywords such as `index` as column names. Use windowing functions for your problem,  see example below

```
 select color, [index], [USER_ID], organization_code from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by color order by [index]) as ranker from table
) Z where ranker = 1
```

Comment: +1 for the keyword hint. Would add that `user_id` also is a bad column name as it's the name of a function.

Comment: @1_CR or if you absolutly have to use a reserverd key word wrap it in square brackets, like so [index]